# Getting error '80070002' from COM .dll

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, com

I am moving a Classic ASP site from a Windows 2000 server to a Windows 2008 (both dev and prod). I have a .dll that was created in .NET 1.1. The error is occurring when function created in JScript located in this securityUtility.asp creates an ActiveXobject using the dll. The line looks as follows:

function getProfileFromLdap(user, pw){

var aClass, aProfile

aClass =  new ActiveXObject("com.co.comp.security.ldap.LDAPLogin");
...
}

The error that is occurring is:
error '80070002' 
E:\SITES\WWW-COMPANYSITE-COM\SITE\BINS../../siteInc/securityUtility.asp, line 850

I had run the following command to register the dll in the registry:

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\RegAsm" coSecurity.dll /tlb:coSecurity.tlb

I don't know if it's worth mentioning but at one point the site worked perfectly in dev and erring when I attempted to move the site to production. I had moved the site to the new dev server (Windows 2008) so long ago. I had made notes so when I moved it up to production I knew what steps I had taken. I thought perhaps I forgot to record a step so in attempt to retrace what I did, I uninstalled the .dll and went through the steps I had recorded. It is now broken in dev but at one point it was working.

Another thing I'm not sure is worth mentioning is this site was the first site on the new dev server. .NET 1.1 was installed prior to any other framework. 4.0 and 2.0 were installed after the fact. On the prod server 4.0 was installed first and then 1.1. Not sure if that's signficant or not.

- When the dev site was working I had confirmed the items were in the
  registry comparing them to the old production and the new dev
  servers and the new production
- On the old production server there was nothing in the GAC
- The coSecurity.dll is in the same file as the securityUtility.asp
  (the page that the code belongs to).
- The Application pool for the has "enable 32-bit applications" as true
  for both of the new environments
- "Everyone" is granted full rights on the .dll

I'm not sure what I'm missing!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing for those that have been beating their heads against the wall like I was:

- opened a command prompt as administrator
- navigated to where the dll was stored
- unregistered the dll using
  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\RegAsm" /u
  coSecurity.dll
- re-registered the dll by using
  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\RegAsm" coSecurity.dll
  /codebase
- you'll get a regasm warning but should also get the message "Types
  registered successfully"

After that I no longer recieved the error!

Answer (score 0):

In general `HRESULT 80070002` means "File Not Found".

My guess is you are missing a dependency. Try using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see if there are any dependencies which should be included.

Also see [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/31256c30-68b1-4d60-aa89-a536eca1ebbd) for some tips about registering COM servers manually.